# YWeatherAPI throws exception sometime for some latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, yahoo-weather-api

I am using this yahoo weather library for getting weather info. https://github.com/nishanths/YWeatherAPI so i am using this code.

```
 CLLocationDegrees Lat = _course.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees Log = _course.longitude;

CLLocation *LocationAtual=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:Lat longitude:Log];

NSLog(@"latitude %f", LocationAtual.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"longitude %f", LocationAtual.coordinate.longitude);


[[YWeatherAPI sharedManager] temperatureForCoordinate: LocationAtual
                                            success:^(NSDictionary* result)
 {
     NSString* temperature = [result objectForKey:kYWAIndex];
     NSLog(@"The temperature is a pleasant %@ F", result);

 }
                                            failure:^(id response, NSError* error)
 {
     // Yikes, something went wrong
     NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
 }
 ];
```

when i am passing below latitude and longitude. code is working fine and getting weather info.

```
latitude 44.983307
longitude -123.313362
```

but when i am passing these below info. i am getting exception. so it is not working for some latitude and longitude even lat and long is correct because it is working in android.

```
latitude 39.065983
longitude -76.925858
```

Error:-

```
error = Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7face9e810c0> { URL: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D'Prince%20George's%20MD%20United%20States'&format=json } { status code: 400, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
Age = 0;
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Thu, 19 May 2016 12:45:27 GMT";
Server = ATS;
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
Via = "https/1.1 a10.ue.bf1.yahoo.net (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ])";
"X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
"X-YQL-Host" = "main-bb9eeee2-0d62-11e6-aa18-d4ae52974741";
"Y-Trace" = "BAEAQAAAAAC1DsBcRpDbSAAAAAAAAAAAxeJD1VIoumEAAAAAAAAAAAAFMzFZQeTfAAUzMVlB8htSLwgkAAAAAA--";
```

} },

```
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D'Prince%20George's%20MD%20United%20States'&format=json, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b226572 726f7222 3a7b226c 616e6722 3a22656e 2d555322 2c226465 73637269 7074696f 6e223a22 51756572 79207379 6e746178 20657272 6f722873 29205b6c 696e6520 313a3538 206d6973 73696e67 20454f46 20617420 2773275d 227d7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}

2016-05-19 08:45:27.485 GolfSmash[22419:2146748] error = Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)"
```

kindly have a look what i am missing.

Comment: Related (with fix): https://github.com/nishanths/YWeatherAPI/issues/4

Comment: @nishanths Thank you. You fixed my issue.